# How to register multiple taxonomies for Woocommerce custom attributes?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been using the Woocommerce documentation to get custom attributes in my wordpress navigation menu:

https://woocommerce.com/document/using-custom-attributes-in-menus/

I used the following code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_attribute_show_in_nav_menus', 'wc_reg_for_menus', 1, 2);

function wc_reg_for_menus( $register, $name = '' ) {
     if ( $name == 'pa_druivensoort') $register = true;
     return $register;
}
```

This works, but how should I modify the code to register multiple of these custom taxonomies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if I can help you out.
What I think you can do is use the PHP OR operator that is basically two pipes "||". The OR operator works by combining the conditions and then PHP executes the if-block if at least one of the conditions are true. If both of the conditions are false, then PHP does not execute the if-block statements.
Ofcourse if you have alot of attributes there might be a more effective way to do this but I hope this helps!

Also remeber to make sure that the attributes you want in the navigation menu are archived. You do this by going to **Products** -> **Attributes** then hover your mouse over the attribute and click on Edit. On the edit screen make sure the "Enable archive" check box is checked.

Here is an example of how the function should look like:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_attribute_show_in_nav_menus', 'wc_reg_for_menus', 1, 2);

function wc_reg_for_menus( $register, $name = '' ) {
     if ( $name == 'pa_druivensoort' || 'pa_secondattribute' || 'pa_thirdattribute') $register = true;
     return $register;
}
```